# Chromium asks for MacOSX 10.8 SDK?

Tags: xcode, macos, unix, chromium

As stated in the title, when I try to build chromium, it asks for MacOSX 10.8 SDK when I have the 10.9 and 10.10 versions.
It shows the following error:
`ninja:error:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/mach/exc.defs', needed by 'obj/native_client/src/trusted/service_runtime/sel.gen/native_client/src/trusted/service_runtime/nacl_exc.h', missing and no known rule to make it`

I have deleted the 10.8 SDK

Is there a way I can force chromium to use OSX SDKs 10.9 or 10.10? I need to use the newer versions because of the absence of a function I need in the the older version. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Run this to regenerate the ninja files, and then build:

```
$ GYP_DEFINES="mac_sdk=10.9" gclient runhooks
```

Note that you may run into build issues, as [some kinks are still getting worked out](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=390212) with the 10.9 and Xcode 6 support.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to have GYP_DEFINES exported, like

```
export GYP_DEFINES="mac_sdk=10.9"
```

in my ~/.profile.

Then just simply run command

```
$ gclient runhooks
```